# How to set particular date for month if the date falls below 20 of a month in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to set 7th of every month as default value in JavaScript but it is not displaying

I tried add this line in my function 
`newDate = newDate.setMonth(newDate.getMonth()+1,7);`

```
function showRepmtStDate() {
  var newDate = (addNoDays(document.forms[0].AGRMNTDT.value, noofdays)).toUpperCase();
  if (getAgrDate(newDate) <= 20) {
    newDate = newDate.setMonth(newDate.getMonth(), 7);
  }
  if (getAgrDate(newDate) >= 21) {
    newDate = newDate.setMonth(newDate.getMonth() + 1, 7);
  }
```

If the date falls below 20th of the month `10-JAN-2019`, the field should display `7-FEB-2019`.
If it is above 21st of the month `21-JAN-2019`, the field should display
`7-MAR-2019`.

Comment: `newDate` appears to be a string, not a `Date` object. Re: `toUpperCase()`

Comment: how to get newDate as string in if()?

Comment: It _is_ a string - you want a `Date` object (I believe). What does `addNoDays` return? What does `getAgrDate` take as a parameter? If they are strings you need to convert to `Date`. See: [Converting a string to a date in JavaScript](//stackoverflow.com/q/5619202)

Comment: addNoDays
 return  newDate3.getDate() + "-"+ (admonths[newDate3.getMonth() + 1].substring(0,3)).toUpperCase()  +"-" +y2k(newDate3.getYear());